# Break out part of linq-to-sql expression to a separate function

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have two entity classes:

```
public class Invoice
{
  public int ID { get; set;}
  public int Amount { get { return InvoiceLines.Sum(il => il.Amount); }}
  public EntitySet<InvoiceLines> InvoiceLines {get;set;};
}

public class InvoiceLine
{
  public Invoice Invoice {get;set;}
  public int InvoiceID {get;set;}
  public int Amount {get;set;}
  public string SomeHugeString {get;set;}
}
```

(The real classes are sqlmetal generated, I shortened it down here to get to the point).

Querying for all amounts:

```
var amounts = from i in invoice select i.Amount;
```

This will cause all invoicelines to be lazy loaded with one database call per invoice. I can solve it with data load options, but that would cause the entire InvoiceLine objects to be read, including `SomeHugeString`.

Repeating the amount calculation in the query will get a good SQL translation:

```
var amounts = from i in invoice select i.InvoiceLines.Sum(il => il.Amount);
```

I sould like to have linq-to-sql somehow get part of the expression tree from a function/property. Is there a way to rewrite `Invoice.Amount` so that the first amounts query will give the same SQL translation as the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something similar using `AsExpandable()` from [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx):

```
Expression<Func<Invoice, int>> getAmount =
    i => i.InvoiceLines.Sum(il => il.Amount);

var amounts = from i in invoice.AsExpandable() select getAmount.Invoke(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own functions using `IQueryable` interface.

I've used standard NorthWind DB:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<int> CalculateAmounts(this IQueryable<Order> order)
    {
        return from o in order select o.Order_Details.Sum(i => i.Quantity);
    }
}

var amounts = (from o in context.Orders select o).CalculateAmounts();
```

This code generates such SQL:

```
SELECT [t2].[value]
FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [t0]
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(CONVERT(Int,[t1].[Quantity])) AS [value]
    FROM [dbo].[Order Details] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[OrderID] = [t0].[OrderID]
    ) AS [t2]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I tried to avoid, repeating the amount calculations logic in the query. I want that logic in one place, not having to repeat it in the query.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you set the 'SomeHugeString' property to be lazy loaded. This way you can load `InvoiceLine` without getting that huge string, which means you can use `DataLoadOptions.LoadWith()`:

[image: Set a single property to be delay loaded by right clicking it, selecting properties and then setting the Delay Loaded property to True]